# How to get state of scoped component instance in Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to take advantage of Spring's Scopes(Prototype or Request) while being able to get the state of these scoped components.

Given the following example

```
@RestController
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooController {
    private FooService fooService;

    @Autowired
    public FooController(FooService fooService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String foo() {
        fooService.foo();
        return "OK";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo/status")
    public int fooStatus() {
        return fooService.getState();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooService
{
    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    private int state;

    public FooService() { }

    public void foo() {
       //do long work
        state++;
       //do long work
       state++;
    }

}
```

There is a Controller and a Service, prototyped scoped. How can I get the `state` of `FooService`.

The code above isn't working. Maybe something with scopes? `status` is always zero.

The scenario is to hit `/foo/status` endpoint and get the `status` value.

Comment: what's wrong with your code ? any error ?

Comment: There is no error. Something's wrong with the logic.

Comment: What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? "isn't working" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: I'm expecting status to increase but it's always zero.

Comment: When doing what? Be precise. Describe your test scenario in details. Anyway, your code is not thread safe: you're accessing mutable state from multiple threads without any synchronization.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the answer 0 is expected. Because the spring prototype scope says that you'll get a new instance of the bean, everytime it's requested.

https://www.journaldev.com/21039/spring-bean-scopes

If you use request or prototype scope, it means that with every request new service bean is created with default State variable initialised to 0.

When you first call `/foo` a new bean of service is created and the State is increased to 2. Next when you call `/foo/status` new bean with default State 0 is created and returned. Which essentially means that state can't be shared between two requests with these bean scopes.
Remove the @scope on the service and controller it should start working fine.

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be Prototype or at least Request scoped.

Comment: If you want it request scope, which means that with every request new service bean is created with default State variable  initialised to 0. When you first call /foo a new bean of service is created and the State is increased to 2. Next when you call /foo/status new bean with default State 0 is created and returned

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? Without removing the Scope.

Comment: You can create a State object with a singleton scope (which is default scope) and autowire it in Service class

Comment: Hmm then I have single state for all Service instances. I want the state of each instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202588/discussion-between-antony-and-codeman).

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a business logic component which is recreated on each HTTP request and keeps no track of status.

I guess you have 2 options:

- remove the scope annotation that recreates your component on each request and change your actual logic / architecture (which is as you say not what you want),
- define the status variable as `static` (not recommended). When 2 services run simultaneously your `foo` method you have to make your incrementation of status thread-save.